# Angular 2 with MVC 5 (Creating new component)

Tags: angular

I'm working on a project that is using angular 2 with MVC 5 framework. I've managed to run the project through this guide: http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/

Now, I want to create one new component (test.component). The folder structure is [Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJY4E.png)

When I add the references to the component. It prompted the error of not being able to find the test.component.

**boot.ts**

```
///<reference path="./../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts"/>
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, TestComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <h1>This is cool</h1>
      <fa-test></fa-test>      
  `,

})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'ASP.NET MVC 5 with Angular 2';
    skills = ['MVC 5', 'Angular 2', 'TypeScript', 'Visual Studio 2015'];
    myskills = this.skills[1];
}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'fa-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {
}
```

**ERROR PICTURE**

[image: Error]

Comment: Please also post the error.

Comment: Included the error in question

Comment: Ok so your test component is unable to find your html file at the specified location.Try giving the absolute url to the template file or try moving your html file to the dist/app folder and give the absolute url in `templateUrl`.